# How to host 2 or more .NET Core 3.1 API web API as single windows service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

We have an existing two .NET Core 3.1 API web application in the same solution which I'd like to host as a windows service and also run in DEBUG from Visual Studio.

We have a lot of examples of how to host one API to one windows service and I have also used it and it works.
But now we need to hosts many APIs on one Windows Service. Also, each API has his own appsettings.json.

What I have tried to do:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));

        if (isService)
        {
            var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
            var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathToContentRoot);
        }
        var service = new CustomHostService();
        if (isService)
        {
            ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = { service };
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
        }
        else
        {

            service.OnStart();
            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
}
```

in CustomHostService wherein the OnStart method I am going to run both service API 1 & 2, like

```
 partial class CustomHostService: ServiceBase
 {
   private IWebHost host1;
   private IWebHost host2;
   ...
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
   {
            new Thread(
                delegate ()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        host1 = Service1.Api.Program.CreateWebHostBuilder(args.Where(arg => arg != "--console").ToArray(), _configuration).Build();

                        // Start the web app
                        host1.Run();

                        Log.Logger.Information("Web API 1 started.");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Error("WindowsService - Failed to start the API 1 Web App: {0}", e);

                        Environment.Exit(1);
                    }
                }
            ).Start();

            new Thread(
                delegate ()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        host2 = Service2.Api.Program.CreateWebHostBuilder(args.Where(arg => arg != "--console").ToArray(), _configuration).Build();

                        // Start the web app
                        host2.Run();

                        Log.Logger.Information("Web API 2 started.");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Error("WindowsService - Failed to start the API 2 Web App: {0}", e);

                        Environment.Exit(1);
                    }
                }
            ).Start();
   }
   ...
 }
```

Could you suggest is it the correct way or not?

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `we need to hosts many APIs on one Windows Service. Also each api has his own appsettings.json.` Can you clarify more about it and what scenario requires each api has a separate appsettings.json in same project?

Comment: You only really need 1 host. That host can load more than 1 service. Your services shouldn't be tightly bound to the host.